# SQL select step

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, modulo

I need to fetch a number of rows between two column values, using a defined step value. For example, if the table looks like this:

```
Id  Name
-----------------------
1   Maria Anders 
2   Christina Berglund
3   Francisco Chang
4   Roland Mendel
5   Diego Roel
6   Eduardo Saavedra
7   Helen Bennett
8   Philip Cramer
```

and `First = 3, Last = 7, Step = 2`, query should return:

```
Id  Name
-----------------------
3   Francisco Chang
5   Diego Roel
7   Helen Bennett
```

I was thinking of using a modulo to specify which columns should be returned, with something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table 
WHERE (i-3) % 2 = 0
```

This approach will result in SQL Server iterating through the entire table and calculating the expression for each item. Since I expect to have relatively large step values, I would like to know if there is a strategy which would avoid this (possible using an index to "skip" items).

Is there a better (read: faster) way of doing this? (I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2)

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: The only option that occurs to me is to create a list of IDs then join that list to the table (just like GBN's answer). But, personally I think it's unlikely that you'll find such options any better. If the @step is significantly large, then maybe, though I don't know how large would be significant, probably when you get to the point that you are ignoring whole pages of records (if you're loading the page anyway, be it it for 50% or 1% or the records, you already have completed a significantly large part of your overhead). Scan and discard (your answer) feels like the optimial solution to me.

Comment: "I feel that if would be more efficient for the server to have a simple skip command" - So essentially, you're saying that you want to be able to tell the RDBMS *how* to access the records, rather than specifying *which* records need to be accessed? If so, I suggest you write your own DBMS - SQL doesn't work that way.

Comment: @MarkBannister: The statement about a *simple skip command* was not supposed to be a "feature request". Basically, yes, if there are two ways to get the same end result, I would like to tell the DBMS *which one to use*. To some extent, I can rely on SQL Server (or generally any compiler) to optimize the execution plan for me, but manually rewriting an inefficient query can sometimes mean a lot.

Comment: @Groo: Actually, what you are asking for is more than a simple feature request; SQL is a set-based language, that allows users to select based on the values in the sets, not on the method used to access those values. Essentially, your request is not possible in SQL. Your comment's example will be dependant on the complexity of your underlying query, indexes set up on the table and the RDBMS engine being used; even where different query plans are produced, this is because the *optimiser* has determined a different query path, not the user.

Comment: @Mark: sorry, but you're missing the point. What I am asking is obviously **possible** in at least two ways, one of them shown by gbn below. The way I proposed in my question requires iterating the entire table, **regardless** of the indexes. gbn's answer shows a way to allow SQL Server utilize an index, and is in that sense an improvement. I have complete

Comment: @Groo: At no point in your question, or in any of the comments until now, have you mentioned that you wanted to use the index instead of performing a table scan. And gbn's answer does not directly tell the optimiser to skip a record - although by producing a **sargable** expression, it does give the optimiser the option to use an index.

Comment: @Dems: Thanks, you could add this as an answer, it's helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @start int = 3,  @step int = 2,  @stop int = 7;

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT @start AS ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID + @step FROM cte WHERE ID + @step <= @stop
)

SELECT * 
FROM cte JOIN MyTable M ON cte.ID = MyTable.ID
```

Comment: Except that realistically @stop should be calculated?  *(Just the MAX(id) of the table?)*

Comment: @Dems - says who? Not the OP, they specified an end which was not the last record!

Comment: Although this is a correct answer, it's likely to only be beneficial for large step sizes (as @Dems suggested above), and I expect it to do much worse for large ranges on large tables/indexes with small step sizes (I just know someone's going to challenge me to a test case now :))

Comment: @Tao: thanks for the comment, I suspected this to be the case actually. Most likely I will stick to my initial query anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from table
where (id >= @start) 
AND (id<=@end) 
AND ((id-@start)%@step) = 0
```

Test case:

```
declare @start int =3,
@end int = 7,
@step int =2
;with t(id)
as
(
    select 1
    union select 2
    union select 3
    union select 4
    union select 5
    union select 6
    union select 7
    union select 8
)
select * from t
where (id >= @start) AND (id<=@end) and ((id-@start)%@step) = 0
```

output:

```
3
5
7
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as the OP already has. The op is asking if there is an alternative that doesn't need to do `((id-@start)%@step) = 0` for every record.  This is not an alternative, it's a clone.

Comment: @Dems - read again, mine differs from the OP in a subtle but crucial way (Subtle in that mine works and the OP's doesnt!!)

Comment: I agree with @Dems, this is not helpful. The fact that I omitted the range was because the part that bothers me is how to implement the step.

Comment: @Groo - Its not the range you were missing, it was the step you had wrong. You had `(i-3) % 2 = 2` which is incorrect, it should have been `(i-3) % 2 = 0` which is what ive demonstrated. But whatev... dont like the answer no worries :)

Comment: That's obviously correct, it was a typo, and I wouldn't call it subtle. ;)

Comment: Obvious to who? Me or you? And I *would* call that subtle.

Comment: IMHO obvious to anyone who has a clue of what modulo means. That error has nothing to do with SQL or the problem I am facing. My question wasn't "Guys, help, my query isn't working", it was (supposed to be) "How do I prevent SQL from iterating through the entire table". Instead, I got your answer correcting my typo, and @MarkBannister's comments suggesting me to "write my own RDBMS". I am, of course, solely responsible for not expressing my problem clearly enough.